# scrapy CrawlerProcess() run my input field twice

Tags: python, scrapy

I made a script to ask you to input some words and it will search about it
my code

```
class Amazon_spiders(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazon"
    start = time.time( )
    search = []
    starting=[]
    parse_number=0
    number = input('Enter the number of times to search \n')
    for n in range(int(number)):
        word = input("Enter one sentence to be searched  \n ")
        search.append(word)
        words = word.strip()
        # replace space with +
        words = word.replace(' ', '+')
        url = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={words}&ref=nb_sb_noss'
        starting.append(url)
    start_urls=starting
    def start_requests(self,response):
        print(f'currant page {response.url}')
        yield Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse_url)
```

the Error is it ask me twice to enter a word:

[see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAIKG.jpg)

another Error TypeError: start_requests() missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'
and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

We're supposed to be nice, but how can this problem not be obvious to you?  You ask for the input every time you go through the loop.  If you want to ask for the word once but add it to the list multiple times, then that's what you should do.  That means moving your `for n in range(int(number)):` to immediately before `starting.append(url)` (and adjusting the indentation to match.

Or, you don't even need a loop:

```
starting.extend( [url] * int(number) )
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I didn't anderstand  what should i do can you write full code after editing and can you solve another problem  start_requests() missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'  when i run the script